# Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

This is a variation on [plpgsql function that returns multiple columns gets called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999187/plpgsql-function-that-returns-multiple-columns-gets-called-multiple-times?rq=1). However, I was hoping to find a solution to my particular set of circumstances.

I have a function that processes an array of rows with a given parameter, and returns a set of rows + a new column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE foo(data data[], parameter int) RETURNS SETOF enhanceddata AS
...
```

The function works on a test case with only 1 set of data

```
SELECT * FROM foo( (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(data) FROM datatable GROUP BY dataid WHERE dataid = something), 1)
```

But I would like to make it work with multiple groups of data, without passing a `dataid` to the function. I tried a number of variations of:

```
SELECT dataid, (foo(ARRAY_AGG(data)),1).*
FROM dataset
WHERE dataid = something -- only testing on 1
GROUP BY dataid
```

But the function gets called once for every column.

Comment: And `enhanceddata` is a composite type, I presume? The definition of which would be essential to your question. Because the problem you describe only applies if multiple *columns* are returned (not for multiple rows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Postgres 9.3 or later, it's typically best to use **`LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`**:

```
SELECT sub.dataid, f.*
FROM  (
   SELECT dataid, array_agg(data) AS arr
   FROM   dataset
   WHERE  dataid = something
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL foo(sub.arr) f ON true;
```

If the function `foo()` can return *no rows*, that's the safe form as it preserves all rows to the left of the join, even when no row is returned to the right.

Else, or if you *want* to exclude rows without result from the lateral join, use:

```
CROSS JOIN LATERAL foo(sub.arr)
```

or the shorthand:

```
, foo(sub.arr)
```

[There is an  explicit mention in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

Craig's related answer (referenced by Daniel) is updated accordingly:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

The function is called multiple times in this context not because of its inputs, but because of how `func().*` is implemented

This is explained at:
[How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query)

The following variant should work without multiple evals on all supported PostgreSQL versions (8.4 or newer):

```
WITH subq as (
  SELECT array_agg(data) as agg,
   dataid FROM datatable
   -- WHERE clause ?
   GROUP BY dataid)
SELECT foo(agg,dataid) FROM subq;
```

Comment: Explanation and link are on target, and the OP accepted. But the actual code provided fails to solve the problem of decomposing the composite type returned from the function call.