# How to get elements with a unique number from a json array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb, set-returning-functions

I have a table `bank_accounts`:

```
    Column     |         Type          |                                Modifiers                                | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
---------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer               | not null default nextval('bank_accounts_id_seq'::regclass)              | plain    |              | 
 name          | character varying(50) |                                                                         | extended |              | 
 bank_accounts | jsonb                 | not null                                                                | extended |              |
```

And it has some JSON in the `jsonb` column:

```
 id | name  |                              bank_accounts                               
----+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | test1 | [{"name": "acct1", "balance": -500}, {"name": "acct2", "balance": -300}]
```

And I am using jsonb_array_elements to get a list of the accounts for one user:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(bank_accounts)->>'name' as name, jsonb_array_elements(bank_accounts)->>'balance' as balance from bank_accounts;
 name  | balance 
-------+---------
 acct1 | -500
 acct2 | -300
```

That's all great. But how do I get each row to have a unique id? I'd like to map each row to a hibernate object, but I'm having trouble doing that because I can't find a way to get each row to have a unique id.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try a different, clean approach with `JOIN LATERAL`:

```sql
SELECT b.id, t.rn
     , t.account->>'name' AS name
     , t.account->>'balance' AS balance
FROM   bank_accounts b
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(b.bank_accounts)
                    WITH ORDINALITY AS t (account, rn) ON true;
```

If you don't care for rows with empty or null values in `bank_accounts`, use a simpler `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM   bank_accounts b
     , jsonb_array_elements(b.bank_accounts) WITH ORDINALITY AS t (account, rn);
```

The key ingredient is `WITH ORDINALITY` to produce row numbers for set-returning functions on the fly. It was introduced with Postgres 9.4 - just like `jsonb`.

`rn` is unique per underlying row in `bank_accounts`.
To be unique across the whole result set, combine it with `b.id`.

About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Related:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-)
- [How to turn a simple json(b) int array into an integer[] in PostgreSQL 9.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257650/how-to-turn-a-simple-jsonb-int-array-into-an-integer-in-postgresql-9-4/28258829#28258829inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. Yes, that works perfectly. I need to wrap my head round join lateral and with ordinality..