# Order by the IN value with jsonb array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb, set-returning-functions

I am trying to select records based on the order of array elements of another row:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tester
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(d->'fam')->>'id' 
    FROM tester
    WHERE id='3'
  )
```

I am aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list).

The difference is that I don't know how to dynamically generate the "ordering" value. Is that possible?

The full [fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/35fbb/13/0).

I would like to see results based on the order found in the json data:

```
id  name    d
--  -----   --------
2   barb    {"fam": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}]}
4   jaimie  {"fam": [{"id": 3}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 1}]}
1   bob     {"fam": [{"id": 3}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 4}]}
```

Comment: What should be generating the ordering in your expected result set?  The JSON data in your demo already seems to have the ordering you want.

Comment: Yes but the rows returned aren’t in the same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) in a [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join to preserve the original order of the array:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   tester t1
CROSS  JOIN jsonb_array_elements(t1.d->'fam') WITH ORDINALITY fam(id, ord)
JOIN   tester t ON t.id = fam.id->>'id'
WHERE  t1.id = '3'
ORDER  BY fam.ord;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4be35/4)

Note a subtle difference: The [`IN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) construct in your original query not only removes original order, it also removes duplicates. My query keeps all IDs extracted from the array, duplicate or not, in original order.

The `LATERAL` keyword is optional noise for [table functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS). As is the `AS` keyword for *table* aliases. Would go here:

```
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(d->'fam') WITH ORDINALITY AS fam(id, ord)
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [How to get elements with a unique number from a json array in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604933/how-to-get-elements-with-a-unique-number-from-a-json-array-in-postgresql/29604986#29604986)
- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)