# PostgreSQL jsonb array of objects: how to filter by one of the fields and get the value of the other one

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Suppose we have two columns: `id`, `params`.
`params` is a jsonb column that contains arrays of objects like:

```
[
    {
        "prop": "a",
        "answer": "123"
    },
    {
        "prop": "b",
        "answer": "456"
    }
]
```

I need to create a query that returns `id` + `answer` where `prop` has some specific value (so at most one row per `id`).

For example, you can filter by `prop=a`, and in this case, you'll get 123 for that particular row. Other rows (with other ids) can have a different value or don't have it all (since there could be no `prop=a` in their jsons).

I tried some solutions with `jsonb_array_elements(params)`  but I always ended up having all possible values from the json even if you have `prop=a` only in one of the elements (so `id` is duplicated in the result set with each `answer`).
Also, I obviously cannot use solutions based on ordinality of the elements in the arrays.

Comment: Use `jsonb_array_elements()` in a lateral join and then filter the exploded array with a `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was suggested by Mike Organek, you can use `jsonb_array_elements()` function.
The final query can be as follows:

```
select id, 
       tmp.parameters->>'prop' AS property, 
       tmp.parameters->>'answer' AS answer
from data
left join LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(data.params) 
          WITH ORDINALITY AS tmp (parameters, row_number) ON true
where tmp.parameters->>'prop' = 'a';
```

Lateral join unwrappes jsonb object (top-level elements) and you get separate columns corresponding for `'prop'` and `'answer'` properties in a jsonb column.
Use `where` clause to filter the rows the way you need.

Here is a **[demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zdhp4gzp)**.

Also more can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604986/20666497).

Answer (score 1):

First flatten the table and then filter as suggested by Mike Organek. `the_table` CTE is a mimic of a real data table.

```sql
with the_table(id, params) as
(
 values
 (1, '[{"prop": "a", "answer": "123"},{"prop": "b", "answer": "456"}]'::jsonb),
 (2, '[{"prop": "a", "answer": "124"},{"prop": "b", "answer": "457"}]'),
 (3, '[{"prop": "a", "answer": "124"},{"prop": "c", "answer": "458"}]')
)
select id, j ->> 'answer' answer
from the_table cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(params) j
where j ->> 'prop' = 'b';
```

| id | answer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 456 |
| 2 | 457 |