# How to filter rows on nested values in a json column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, nested

Here is my table (simplified, only significant columns):

```
CREATE TABLE things (
  id serial primary key
, name varchar
, blueprint json default '{}'
);
```

And some sample data:

```
# select * from things;

 id |  name   |                                  blueprint
----+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | Thing 1 | {}
  2 | Thing 2 | {"1":{"name":"Iskapola","wight":"2"}}
  3 | Thing 3 | {"1":{"name":"Azamund","weight":"3"}, "2":{"name":"Iskapola","weight":"1"}}
  4 | Thing 4 | {"1":{"name":"Ulamir","weight":"1"}, "2":{"name":"Azamund","weight":"1"}}
```

I'd like to select rows that have `'Azamund'` anywhere under the `name` key.
Something like this:

```
# select * from things where * ->> 'name' = 'Azamund';

 id |      blueprint
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  7 | {"1":{"name":"Azamund","weight":"3"}, "2":{"name":"Iskapola","weight":"1"}}
  8 | {"1":{"name":"Ulamir","weight":"1"}, "2":{"name":"Azamund","weight":"1"}}
```

Data is nested exactly like in the sample (only one level).
Currently we are using PostgreSQL 9.3.5.

Is it possible in PostgreSQL 9.3? Maybe 9.4?

Comment: I am not sure but this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype

Comment: Thank you! I saw that question... But the difference here - I can not write down key path to the `name` column... It can be under `'1'` or `'9'` key. And I still should be able to locate it. Anyway - thank you. I've add more details in question to highlight it... (hope it's clear)

Comment: So there is exactly one level of nesting? Also, actual table definitions are *always* helpful. The data type could be `text` or `json` or `jsonb`? ... `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - added more information about table schema. Is it OK?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't use a JSON array like `'[{"name":"Azamund","weight":"3"}, {"name":"Iskapola","weight":"1"}]'` Note the square brackets. Or even a normalized db schema without JSON?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter sure I can change schema and migrate data... If there is no simple/pretty way to retrieve data. And do not want to normalize this data... `blueprint` can contains other keys (other than name/weight) and that keys is unknown.

Comment: I took the liberty to consolidate your question as I figure I may be referring to it in the future. I hope I caught the gist of it?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter nice refactoring =) :+1:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is close. [**`json_each()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) is the key function. Or `jsonb_each()` for `jsonb`. A couple of improvements:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   things t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM json_each(t.blueprint) b
   WHERE  b.value->>'name' ILIKE 'azamund'
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SIe1pHpt)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/84407/10)</sub>

`json_each()` already returns `json` values. No need for an additional cast.

Better, yet, use a `LATERAL` reference in `EXISTS`. This is much cleaner than unnesting with a set-returning function in the `SELECT` list. See:

- [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)

Use `ILIKE` for the pattern match. Regular expression matches (`~`, `~*`) are more versatile, but also more expensive. So use the basic `LIKE` / `ILKE` where you can. See:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

#### Alternative with JSON array

You have already seen my related answer for JSON arrays:

- [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)

While the query for nested JSON objects seems just as simple, there is superior **index support** for the array:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

#### With [JSON/PATH expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) in Postgres 12+

The syntax is complex, but the query becomes simpler and more efficient. Can also use an index of the form:

```
CREATE INDEX things_blueprint_gin_idx ON things USING gin (blueprint);
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   things t
WHERE  t.blueprint @? '$.* ? (@.name == "Azamund")';
```

Case insensitive:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   things t
WHERE  t.blueprint @? '$.* ? (@.name like_regex "^azamund$" flag "i")';
```

For the array variant, we can also use an index with the more efficient operator class `jsonb_path_ops`:

```
CREATE INDEX things_arr_foo_path_ops ON things_arr USING gin (blueprint jsonb_path_ops);
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   things_arr t
WHERE  t.blueprint @? '$[*] ? (@.name == "Azamund")';
```

Case insensitive:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   things_arr t
WHERE  t.blueprint @? '$[*] ? (@.name like_regex "^azamund$" flag "i")';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SIe1pHpt)*

Related:

- [jsonb query with nested objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108179/jsonb-query-with-nested-objects-in-an-array/29114520#29114520)
- [Search a JSON array for an object containing a value matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824466/search-a-json-array-for-an-object-containing-a-value-matching-a-pattern/49826693#49826693)

Comment: Nice improvements! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Closest query I can execute (that returns data I need) is:

```
select *
from (select id, (json_each(blueprint)).value::json->>'name' as name
      from stocks) as t
where t.name ~* 'azamund';
```

Well... Maybe there is something better?