# Filter rows by given key/value pair in a jsonb column

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have the next table in Postgres 9.4

```
CREATE TABLE public.neuro (
    nid int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('neuro_nid_seq'::regclass),
    data jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT neuro_pkey PRIMARY KEY (nid) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);
```

with the records:

```
{"item2": {"1": "0", "uid": "0", "nota": "weqcqwe qwe wq", "fecha": "23-02-2015", "examen": "aesc", "puntaje": "0", "paciente": "103636426"}}
{"item2": {"1": "0", "uid": "0", "nota": "text", "fecha": "23-02-2015", "examen": "aesc", "puntaje": "0", "paciente": "103636426"}}
{"item3": {"1": "3", "2": "1", "3": "3", "uid": "0", "fecha": "23-02-2015", "examen": "fab", "puntaje": "7", "paciente": "103636426"}}
...
```

How to select all records with `examen ='aesc'`? I tried using the operators `->>` or `@`. How to select some fields in the same way? I need to maintain the initial "itemX" in a jSON column.

Comment: with your data setup, I'm not quite sure of a very efficient mehod-- however, you could use "like" on the text representation of the json...

Comment: How many levels of nesting in your JSON objects?

Answer (score 3):

Since your JSON objects seem to be nested exactly *one* level, you could unnest one level with `jsonb_each()` and search the value part of the dynamic key name (which we ignore this way):

```
SELECT n.*
FROM   public.neuro n, jsonb_each(n.data) d
WHERE  d.value->>'examen' = 'aesc'
```

Related:

- [How to filter rows on nested values in a json column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543311/how-to-filter-rows-on-nested-values-in-a-json-column/28549214#28549214)
- [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)