# jsonb query with nested objects in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 with a table `teams` containing a `jsonb` column named `json`. I am looking for a query where I can get all teams which have the Players `3`, `4` and `7` in their array of players.

The table contains two rows with the following `json` data:

First row:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foobar",
    "members": {
        "coach": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A dude"
        },
        "players": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "B dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "C dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "D dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "F dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "G dude"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

second row:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bazbar",
    "members": {
        "coach": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "A dude"
        },
        "players": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "C dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "E dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "F dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "G dude"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "H dude"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How does the query have to look like to get the desired list of teams? I've tried a query where I'd create an array from the member players `jsonb_array_elements(json -> 'members' -> 'players')->'id'` and compare them, but all I was able to accomplish is a result where any of the compared player ids was available in a team, not all of them.

Comment: You should add the query you had, even if it's not working - it may be part of a solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are facing two non-trivial tasks at once.

- Process `jsonb` with a complex nested structure.
- Run the equivalent of a relational division query on the document type.

First `jsonb_populate_recordset()` works with a registered row type. Can be the row type of any (temp) table or view, or a composite type explicitly created with `CREATE TYPE`. If there is none, register one. For ad-hoc use, a temporary type does the job (undocumented hack, dropped automatically at the end of the session):

```
CREATE TYPE pg_temp.foo AS (id int);  -- just "id"
```

We only need `id`, so don't include `name`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

> JSON fields that do not appear in the target row type will be omitted from the output

### Query with index support

If you need it fast, create a **GIN index** on the `jsonb` column. The more specialized [operator class `jsonb_path_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) is even faster than the default `jsonb_ops`:

```
CREATE INDEX teams_json_gin_idx ON teams USING GIN (json jsonb_path_ops);
```

Can be used by the "contains" operator `@>`:

```sql
SELECT t.json->>'id' AS team_id
     , ARRAY (SELECT * FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(null::foo, t.json#>'{members,players}')) AS players
FROM   teams t
WHERE  json @> '{"members":{"players":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":7}]}}';
```

[SQL/JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) path language in Postgres 12+ can use the same index:

```sql
SELECT t.json->>'id' AS team_id
     , ARRAY (SELECT * FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(null::foo, t.json#>'{members,players}')) AS players
FROM   teams t
WHERE  json @? '$.members ? (@.players.id == 3) ? (@.players.id == 4) ? (@.players.id == 7)';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2c13c41da316db908cb41600093a1a8f)*

See:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684)
- [Update all values for given key nested in JSON array of objects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251181/3684)

### Simple query

Without index support - unless you create a tailored expression index, see below.

```sql
SELECT t.json->>'id' AS team_id, p.players
FROM   teams t
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT * FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(null::foo, t.json#>'{members,players}')
      )
   ) AS p(players) ON p.players @> '{3,4,7}';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2c13c41da316db908cb41600093a1a8f)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c9e55/6)</sub>

#### How?

Extracts the JSON array with player records:

```
t.json#>'{members,players}'
```

From these, I unnest rows with just the `id` with:

```
jsonb_populate_recordset(null::foo, t.json#>'{members,players}')
```

... and immediately aggregate those into a Postgres array, so we keep one row per row in the base table:

```
SELECT ARRAY ( ... )
```

All of this happens in a lateral join:

```
, JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ... ) AS p(players) ...
```

- Immediately filter the resulting arrays in the join condition to keep only the ones we are looking for - with the ["contains" *array* operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

  ... ON p.players @> '{3,4,7}'

If you run this query a lot on a big table, you could create a fake `IMMUTABLE` function that extracts the array like above and create functional **GIN index** based on this function to make this super fast.
"Fake" because the function depends on the underlying row type, i.e. on a catalog lookup, and would change if that changes. (So make sure it does not change.) Similar to this one:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

Aside:
Don't use type names like `json` as column names (even if that's allowed), that invites tricky syntax errors and confusing error messages.

Comment: That looks very promising! Thank you for your in-depth answer.
I'll check it out later tonight and let you know, but the SQL Fiddle (even though it's 9.3) looks very good.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter I have a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711199/jsonb-like-query-on-nested-objects-in-an-array If you can please answer the same. It will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Figured it out and posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same as above. Only other condition was I had to do substring matching and not an exact matching.

This is what I ended up doing(inspired from the answer above of course)

```
SELECT t.json->>'name' AS feature_name, f.features::text
FROM   teams t
 , LATERAL  (
     SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::foo, t.json#>'{members,features}')
   ) AS f(features)
 WHERE f.features LIKE '%dud%';
```

Posting it here if it is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Consider the added [simpler alternatives under your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44723048/939860).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/

> Subscripting can now be applied to any data type for which it is a
> useful notation, not only arrays. In this release, the jsonb and
> hstore types have gained subscripting operators.
> Let's use subscripting feature in postgresql 14.

```
with a as(
select data['id'] as teamid,
       (jsonb_array_elements( data['members']['players']))['id'] as playerid
from teams), b as( select teamid, array_agg(playerid) as playerids from a group by 1)
select b.* from b where b.playerids @> '{3,4,7}';
```

returns:

```
 teamid |  playerids
--------+-------------
 1      | {2,3,4,6,7}
```

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5434278d95c138a93dc608e8343ece48)