# Query A Nested Array in Parquet Records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, parquet

I am trying different ways to query a record within a array of records and display complete Row as output.

**I dont know which nested Object has String "pg". But i want to query on particular object. Whether the object has "pg" or not. If "pg" exist then i want to display that complete row. How to write "spark sql query" on nested objects without specfying the object index.So i dont want to use the index of children.name**

My Avro Record:

```
{
"name": "Parent",
"type":"record",
"fields":[
    {"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},

    {
        "name":"children",
        "type":{
            "type": "array",
            "items":{
                        "name":"child",
                        "type":"record",
                        "fields":[
                            {"name":"name", "type":"string"}
                        ]
                    }
            }
    }
]
}
```

I am using Spark SQL context to query dataframe which is read. 
So if input is

```
Row no   Firstname Children.name
    1    John       Max
                    Pg
    2    Bru        huna
                    aman
```

Output should return poq 1 since it has row where one object of children.name is pg.

```
val results = sqlc.sql("SELECT firstname, children.name FROM nestedread where children.name = 'pg'")
results.foreach(x=> println(x(0), x(1).toString))
```

The above query doesn't work. but it works when i query children[1].name.

**I ALSO want to know that if i can filter a set of records and then explode. Instead of first explode and create large number of rows and then filter.**

Comment: children is an Array, children.name does not mean anything. children[1].name means you access to the first object in that array, and you read name attribute.

Comment: Yes. But i want to query on particular object. Whether the object has pg or not. If pg exist then i want to display that complete row. How to write "sql query" on nested objects without specfying the object index.

Comment: Have you checked this one : http://bender.io/2013/09/22/returning-hierarchical-data-in-a-single-sql-query/ ?

Comment: Also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108179/jsonb-query-with-nested-objects-in-an-array

Comment: If the answer provided solves your question please accept it to close the question !

Comment: Hi @eliasah I have answered my q. But where to close my question?

Comment: There is an accept button next to the question under the votes

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you can use

```
org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(e: Column): Column
```

for example in my project(in java), i have nested json like this:

```
{
    "error": [],
    "trajet": [
        {
            "something": "value"
        }
    ],
    "infos": [
        {
            "something": "value"
        }
    ],
    "timeseries": [
        {
            "something_0": "value_0",
            "something_1": "value_1",
            ...
            "something_n": "value_n"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i wanted to analyse datas in "timeseries", so i did:

```
DataFrame ts = jsonDF.select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(jsonDF.col("timeseries")).as("t"))
                     .select("t.something_0",
                             "t.something_1",
                             ...
                             "t.something_n");
```

I'm new to spark too. Hope this could give you a hint.

Comment: Hi, thanxs. I found a way through Explode. 
val results = sqlc.sql("SELECT firstname, child.name,  FROM parent LATERAL VIEW explode(children) childTable AS child ")

Comment: I ALSO want to know that if i can filter a set of records and then explode. Instead of first explode and create large number of rows and then filter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by

I found a way through Explode.

```
val results = sqlc.sql("SELECT firstname, child.name, FROM parent LATERAL VIEW explode(children) childTable AS child
```