# jsonb LIKE query on nested objects in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

My JSON data looks like this:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "payload": {
    "location": "NY",
    "details": [{
            "name": "cafe",
            "cuisine": "mexican"
        },
        {
            "name": "foody",
            "cuisine": "italian"
        }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "payload": {
    "location": "NY",
    "details": [{
            "name": "mbar",
            "cuisine": "mexican"
        },
        {
            "name": "fdy",
            "cuisine": "italian"
        }
    ]
  }
}]
```

given a text "foo" I want to return all the tuples that have this substring. But I cannot figure out how to write the query for the same.

I followed [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108179/jsonb-query-with-nested-objects-in-an-array) but cannot figure out how to do `LIKE`.
This is what I have working right now:

```
SELECT r.res->>'name' AS feature_name, d.details::text
  FROM   restaurants r
    , LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY (
     SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::foo, r.res#>'{payload, 
       details}')
     )
   ) AS d(details)
 WHERE d.details @> '{cafe}';
```

Instead of passing the whole text of `cafe` I want to pass `ca` and get the results that match that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution can be simplified some more:

```sql
SELECT r.res->>'name' AS feature_name, d.name AS detail_name
FROM   restaurants r
     , jsonb_populate_recordset(null::foo, r.res #> '{payload, details}') d
WHERE  d.name LIKE '%oh%';
```

Or simpler, yet, with [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) since you don't actually need the row type (`foo`) at all in this example:

```sql
SELECT r.res->>'name' AS feature_name, d->>'name' AS detail_name
FROM   restaurants r
     , jsonb_array_elements(r.res #> '{payload, details}') d
WHERE  d->>'name' LIKE '%oh%';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2b69ad3b55048b79430207a8666115bc)*

But that's ***not*** what you *asked* exactly:

> I want to return all the tuples that have this substring.

You are returning all JSON array elements (0-n per base table row), where one particular key (`'{payload,details,*,name}'`) matches (case-sensitively).

And your original question had a nested JSON array on top of this. You removed the outer array for this solution - I did the same.

Depending on your actual requirements the [new text search capability of Postgres 10](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=e306df7f9cd6b4433273e006df11bdc966b7079e) might be useful.

Comment: Yes correct. But I have the ids, name of the top level tuple. This is what I am going to return(the ids that have the substr). Thanks for the observation though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this(inspired by this answer - [jsonb query with nested objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108179/jsonb-query-with-nested-objects-in-an-array))

```
SELECT r.res->>'name' AS feature_name, d.details::text
FROM   restaurants r
 , LATERAL  (
     SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::foo, r.res#>'{payload, details}')
   ) AS d(details)
WHERE d.details LIKE '%oh%';
```

Fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f2027/5