# How to filter table rows in nodejs using db queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using `nest js framework` for my demo application. In my demo application I have an entity `Category` which has two columns (`id, description`). `description` is `jsonb` type.

```
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'jsonb' })
  description;
}
```

I inserted some data in my table.

[image]
Now I want to filter that data and only show those rows which have `name = test`.

Currently I'm using the code shown here, which returns all rows. But I need only the rows which have `name equals to test`. Currently there is only one row

```
@Get('/app')
  async getApp(): Promise<Category[]> {
    return this.categoryRepository.find({});
  }
```

Here is my full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-nhqyb?file=/src/app.controller.ts:568-670

You can see filter result like

https://nhqyb-5000.sse.codesandbox.io/app

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2256), it's not possible unless you are writing raw SQL and using database specific syntax.

In Postgres, it would look something like

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Category cat
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT FROM jsonb_each(cat.description) desc
   WHERE  desc.value->>'name' ILIKE 'test'
   );
```

Lots more discussion and in depth answers [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543311/how-to-filter-rows-on-nested-values-in-a-json-column)