# SUM & GROUP BY on an array of composite type

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, aggregate-functions, composite-types

I have a column with an array of composite type `(text, decimal, timestamp)` as data type. I want to create a query to sum the total of the double column of the composite type. Also I want to perform a group by on the date(day-month-year) of the date time.

Can anyone show me an example of explain how this an be done?

Definition of table and type:

```
create type stage as (
   Stage_Name        text,
   Stage_Distance    decimal,
   Stage_Start_Time  timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE "Event" (
  "Id" serial NOT NULL,
  "Location" text,
  "Date_Range" daterange,
  "Surface" text,
  "Stage_Information" stage[],
  CONSTRAINT "PK_Event" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

Example data

```
{"(Newtownards,1.5,\"2015-04-03 18:28:00\")"
,"(\"Bulls Brook\",13.4,\"2015-04-04 09:04:00\")"}
```

Expected results:

Sum(1.5 + 13.4) = 14.9

Group by 2015-04-03, 2015-04-04

Comment: The type is create with double quotes, the table without?

Comment: Yes they are created as shown above

Comment: If you group by day, you get *two* rows with `2015-04-03 | 1.5` and `2015-04-04 | 13.4` ant *not* the sum of both.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: SELECT e.id, s.(st).stage_start_time::date AS day

Comment: Should be fixed now. The opening parenthesis was misplaced in my update. Parentheses need to be around the complete column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming current Postgres version 9.4 for lack of information.

#### Proper design

First of all, consider [**database normalization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). An additional table instead of the column `"Stage_Information"` is typically the superior solution:

```
CREATE TABLE stage (
  stage_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, event_id  int NOT NULL REFERENCES event
, name      text        -- possibly NOT NULL
, distance  numeric     -- possibly NOT NULL
, starttime timestamp   -- possibly NOT NULL
);
```

It doesn't occupy much more disk space either, array overhead is similar to table overhead. Only the additional index needs some more space. But many queries on the base table will be faster, and updates will be *much* cheaper, and everything will be cleaner and simpler.

Don't mix quoted and unquoted capitalization with your identifiers. That is very error prone. Use unquoted, legal, lower-case names exclusively if you can.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

The query would then be:

```
SELECT e.id, s.starttime::date AS day
     , sum(s.distance) AS sum_distance
FROM   "Event" e
LEFT   JOIN stage s ON s.event_id = e.id
WHERE  e.id = 1
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

#### Solution for the problem at hand

While stuck with your current design, you need to [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) the array to apply aggregate functions to its elements. An then you need to decompose the composite values. Use a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT e.id, (s.st).stage_start_time::date AS day
     , sum((s.st).stage_distance) AS sum_distance
FROM   "Event" e
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(e."Stage_Information") s(st) ON true
WHERE  e.id = 1
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

Note the parentheses around `(s.st)` (the column alias for the unnested column). You need those to access elements of a [composite type (row type)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html).

Why `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`?

- [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)

Comment: I now get the ERROR:  column notation .stage_distance applied to type stage[], which is not a composite type
LINE 1: SELECT ("Stage_Information").Stage_Distance::date AS day, Updated question

Comment: @AlanMulligan: Okay, that is an array of composite type. Explains why you had "array" in the title. Requires a more sophisticated approach. What exactly do you want to calculate? The sum for an individual column or over the whole table? Please add your version of Postgres to the question.

Comment: I need to sum Stage_Distance where id = 1 and select Stage_Start_Time where id = 1 group by Stage_Start_Time (day-month--year) if they make sence

Comment: @AlanMulligan: You cannot select the time *and* group by the day at once. Logically contradictory. Please add example values and the desired result to your question if you find it hard to explain.