# How to insert the output of set-returning function into a table

Tags: postgresql, function, row, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I have a function taking two parameters, returns some data from tables. Want to insert the returned rows to a temp table (with same structure as function output) in another function.

Tried like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp1 (col1 int,  col2 int) ON COMMIT DROP;

WITH x as (select function_name(p1, p2))
    insert into tmp1 select * from x;
```

The function `RETURNS TABLE(val1 integer, val2 integer)`

The select does not work.

```
ERROR:  column "col1" is of type integer but expression is of type record
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

What shall I do?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
I am able to do it using "select * from function" .. !!

Answer (score 4):

and this way?..

```
insert into tmp1 select * from function_name(p1, p2);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an important difference between these two queries:

```
select * from function_name(1, 2);
select function_name(1, 2);
```

The first query returns rows with **two** columns (as your function returns table with two columns). The second one returns rows with **one** column of pseudo-type record.

You can use `with` query as in the question, but you should place the function call in `from` clause:

```
WITH x as (select * from function_name(p1, p2))
    insert into tmp1 select * from x;
```

Of course the query

```
insert into tmp1 select * from function_name(p1, p2);
```

does the same and is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your actual query it may or may not make sense to fetch a **row type** from the function (instead of decomposing the result with `SELECT * FROM function_name(p1, p2)`) in a CTE (or subquery). In some contexts it may be useful to avoid multiple evaluation of the function.

- [JOIN on set returning function results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852929/join-on-set-returning-function-results/28853666#28853666)
- [Combine postgres function with query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961133/combine-postgres-function-with-query/27197155#27197155)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

But if you do, you need the **right syntax** to decompose the row type ***column*** later:

```
WITH x AS (select function_name(p1, p2) f)
INSERT INTO tmp1(col1,  col2)  -- supply a column list
-- SELECT (f).*               -- note the parentheses ...
SELECT (f).val1, (f).val2   -- .... but better yet
FROM   x;
```

You need the parentheses around **`(`**`f`**`)`** (the implicit column alias for the row type) to [**access columns of a composite type (row type)**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html).

- [SUM & GROUP BY on an array of composite type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310815/sum-group-by-on-an-array-of-composite-type/29310898#29310898)

And be sure to supply a column list for the target of the `INSERT` in persisted statements. If you don't this may break in surprising ways if you later change the table layout of `tmp1`.
In this case it is probably also better to target relevant columns of the function result explicitly by name (`(f).val1, (f).val2`) instead of `(f).*`

BTW, the fact that your function is `taking two parameters` is not relevant to the problem at hand. Only the definition of the *return type* matters.