# Find duplicated values on array column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, set-returning-functions

I have a table with a array column like this:

```
my_table
id   array
--   -----------
1    {1, 3, 4, 5}
2    {19,2, 4, 9}
3    {23,46, 87, 6}
4    {199,24, 93, 6}
```

And i want as result what and where is the repeated values, like this:

```
value_repeated    is_repeated_on
--------------    -----------
4                 {1,2}
6                 {3,4}
```

Is it possible? I don't know how to do this. I don't how to start it! I'm lost!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `unnest` to convert the array to rows, and then `array_agg` to build an array from the `id`s

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT v AS value_repeated,array_agg(id) AS is_repeated_on FROM 
(select id,unnest(array) as v from my_table) 
GROUP by v HAVING Count(Distinct id) > 1
```

Note that `HAVING Count(Distinct id) > 1` is filtering values that don't appear even once

Comment: Note that as currently written this will show all possible values; to show only those which appear in at least two places, you need to add a `HAVING` clause, e.g. `HAVING Count(Distinct id) > 1`, or just `HAVING Count(*) > 1` if you're sure the same number will never appear twice within the same array.

Answer (score 3):

The clean way to call a set-returning function like `unnest()` is in a `LATERAL` join, available since Postgres 9.3:

```
SELECT value_repeated, array_agg(id) AS is_repeated_on
FROM   my_table
     , unnest(array_col) value_repeated
GROUP  BY value_repeated
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER  BY value_repeated;  -- optional
```

About `LATERAL`:

- [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)

There is nothing in your question to rule out shortcut duplicates (the same element more than once in the same array ([like I@MSoP commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897501/find-duplicated-values-on-array-column#comment47918347_29897761)), so it must be `count(*)`, not `count (DISTINCT id)`.

Comment: More clean and intuitive.