# How to filter the max value and write to row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

Postgres 9.3.5, PostGIS 2.1.4.

I have tow tables (`polygons` and `points`) in a database.

I want to find out how many `points` are in each `polygon`. There will be 0 points per polygon or more than 200000. The little hick up is the following.

My `point` table looks the following:

```
x    y    lan
10  11    en
10  11    fr
10  11    en
10  11    es
10  11    en
- #just for demonstration/clarification purposes
13  14    fr
13  14    fr
13  14    es
-
15  16    ar
15  16    ar
15  16    ps
```

I do not simply want to count the number of points per polygon. I want to know what is the most often occuring `lan` in each polygon. So, assuming each `-` indicates that the points are falling into a new polygon, my results would look the following:

`Polygon` table:

```
polygon    Count   lan
1          3       en
2          2       fr
3          2       ar
```

This is what I got so far.

```
SELECT count(*), count.language AS language, hexagons.gid AS hexagonsWhere 
  FROM hexagonslan AS hexagons, 
       points_count AS france 
 WHERE ST_Within(count.geom, hexagons.geom) 
 GROUP BY language, hexagonsWhere 
 ORDER BY hexagons DESC;
```

It gives me the following:

```
Polygon    Count     language
1          3         en
1          1         fr
1          1         es
2          2         fr
2          1         es
3          2         ar
3          1         ps
```

Two things remain unclear.

1. How to get only the max value?
2. How will cases be treated where there are by any chance the max values identical?

Comment: The second question should be one answered by you, how do you want those to be treated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select id with max date group by category in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914098/how-to-select-id-with-max-date-group-by-category-in-postgresql)

Comment: @JakubKania I wonder wether it raises an error or gives me note that that happened or something. Thats all.

Comment: It's a classic case of groupwise max (once you throw away the performance of that `ST_Within`  and the insert) so you should decide if you want an error or not.

Comment: @JakubKania what do you mean with "once you throw away the performance of that ST_Within and the insert"?

Comment: Do you need the total count of points or just the count of the most common type of points or both?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The count of the most common. I got the total count already. I think I create a new table with the statement I wrote above and use a `DISTINCT` than. That might be the easiest.

Comment: BTW, your query and displayed results don't add up.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter when I run it it adds up the results http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4003/je7ax32a_png.htm Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Stoffer: "does not add up" is a phrase meaning it does not make sense together. You write: `It gives me the following:`, but that's not so.

Comment: Ah ok. I understand. Have a look at the screenshot I posted. Thats what my querry prompts me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to 1.

To get the most common language and its count per Polygon, you could use a simple `DISTINCT ON` query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (h.gid)
       h.gid AS polygon, count(c.geom) AS ct, c.language
FROM   hexagonslan h
LEFT   JOIN points_count c ON ST_Within(c.geom, h.geom)
GROUP  BY h.gid, c.language
ORDER  BY h.gid, count(c.geom) DESC, c.language;  -- language name is tiebreaker
```

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

But for the data distribution you describe (up to 200.000 points per polygon), this should be ***substantially*** faster (hoping to make better use of an index on `c.geom`):

```
SELECT h.gid AS polygon, c.ct, c.language
FROM   hexagonslan h
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT c.language, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   points_count c
   WHERE  ST_Within(c.geom, h.geom) 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 1  -- again, language name is tiebreaker
   LIMIT  1
   ) c ON true
ORDER  BY 1;
```

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

**`LEFT JOIN`** `LATERAL ..` **`ON true`** preserves polygons not containing any points.

- [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)

In `cases where there are by any chance the max values identical`, the alphabetically first language is picked in the example, by way of the added `ORDER BY` item. If you want *all* languages that happen to share the maximum count, you have to do more:

#### Answer to 2.

```
SELECT h.gid AS polygon, c.ct, c.language
FROM   hexagonslan h
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT c.language, count(*) AS ct
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   points_count c
   WHERE  ST_Within(c.geom, h.geom) 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c ON c.rnk = 1
ORDER  BY 1, 3  -- language only as additional sort critieria
```

Using the [window function **`rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) here, (not `row_number()`!). We can get the count or points *and* the ranking of the count in a single `SELECT`. Consider the sequence of events:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)